# Get numbers from string

Tags: ruby, regex

I got a string:

```
"1|2 3 4 oh 5 oh oh|e eewrewr|7|".
```

I want to get the digits between first pipes (|), returning "2 3 4 5".

Can anyone help me with the regular expression to do that?

Comment: Don't use a regex when a split is sufficient.

Answer (score 8):

Does this work?

`"1|2 3 4 oh 5 oh oh|e eewrewr|7|".split('|')[1].scan(/\d/)`

Comment: ...and to get numbers, instead of strings, you could append this: .map{|n| n.to_i}

Comment: ... and to the numbers in one string as in your example, you append this instead: `.join(' ')`

Comment: @Nate: How about `.map!{|n| n.to_i}` (Personally, I like to mutate rather than get a new object)

Comment: "1|2 3 4 oh 54 5 oh oh|e eewrewr|7|" will return you: ["2", "3", "4", "5", "4", "5"]

Comment: Use this instead: "1|2 3 4 oh 55 oh oh|e eewrewr|7|".split('|')[1].scan(/\d+/)

Answer (score 6):

[Arun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206398/get-numbers-from-string/1206450#1206450) is perfect if you want only digits.
i.e.

```
"1|2 3 4 oh 5 oh oh|e eewrewr|7|".split('|')[1].scan(/\d/)
 # Will return ["2", "3", "4", "5"]
"1|2 3 4 oh 55 oh oh|e eewrewr|7|".split('|')[1].scan(/\d/)
 # Will return ["2", "3", "4", "5", "5"]
```

If you want numbers instead,

```
# Just adding a '+' in the regex:
"1|2 3 4 oh 55 oh oh|e eewrewr|7|".split('|')[1].scan(/\d+/)
# Will return ["2", "3", "4", "55"]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use just regex...

```
\|[\d\s\w]+\|
```

and then

```
\d
```

but that's probably not the best solution